# Why won't the contents of this div container reach full width?

Tags: html, css, containers, alignment, width

For some reason, the right side of this div container refuses to let the contents achieve full width.

[Image of the issue. Right column is not reaching full width.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exlUx.jpg)

This is my css code.

main-content is the container that extends all the way to the edges of the computer screen in which case full-content or full content flex (if content next to each other) goes inside of this and aligned the middle of the screen. The fifty-fifty-content holds both the left form and right form. I have tried changing the width of the divs, the aligment. Nothing is working. The only css control for the form fields is a master css file.

```
.main-content {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 5px solid #666; 
}

.full-content {
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

.full-content-flex {
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
}

.sixtyfourtycontentleft {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 700px;
    border-right: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}

.fifty-fifty-content {
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: gray;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="url"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="date"],
input[type="number"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="time"] {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    
}

Here is my HTML code

<section class="main-content">
            <section class="full-content-flex">
                    
                  <div class="fifty-fifty-content">
                    <form action="register.php" method="post">
                  
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name or organization name">
                    
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    
                    <input type="password" name="repeatpassword" placeholder="Password Again">
                    
                    <input type="url" name="website"  placeholder="Website">
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Submit & Login">
</form
</div>
<div class="fifty-fifty-content">
                    <form action="register.php" method="post">
                  
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name or organization name">
                    
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                    
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    
                    <input type="password" name="repeatpassword" placeholder="Password Again">
                    
                    <input type="url" name="website"  placeholder="Website">
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit & Login">
</form
</div>
</section
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated this style code

```
    .full-content-flex {
        max-width: 1000px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10px;
        display: flex;
        background-color: gray;     /* add bg color   */
    }

    .fifty-fifty-content {
        /* remove color   */
        flex: 1 0 0%;
    }
    form {
        width: 100%;
    }
    input[type="text"],
    input[type="email"],
    input[type="url"],
    input[type="password"],
    input[type="date"],
    input[type="number"],
    input[type="tel"],
    input[type="time"] {
        width: -webkit-fill-available;
    }
```

So I wish your problem is solved

Comment: This mostly solved it. I still don't understand why setting the width didn't allow it to extend the full width. Why was the webkit fill necessary? Also when I add anything else besides the form fields to the right side, the form fields go back to not the full width. Why? I just want to understand as well.